# How to store JWT and Refresh Tokens in a app or a browser?

Tags: android, jwt, refresh-token

I build a Rest-API which handle request by using JWT and refresh token. But i am not sure how to store it on client side.

Should I store both it in cookies with httponly flag?

Should i store both in cookies or one in local storage for example shared preference(Android App)?

I am very interested in what is the best practice to handle these token on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard recommendations:

- In a mobile UI store tokens in OS secure storage
- In a Web UI store the access token in memory
- In a Web UI refresh tokens in cookies work best

It requires a lot of discipline to do properly. My blog has posts and code samples you can run to understand this stuff. Maybe start here:

- [Browser Token Security](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/08/ui-token-management)
- [Android Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)